# Firefox white spacing

Tags: html, css, whitespace

just built my new site, looks perfect in Chrome but when viewing it on Firefox (OS) there is roughly 15px space at the bottom of the page. Just can't figure out what is causing it.

http://www.adamhuxtable.com/

Comment: Can you please edit the question and create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) by adding the *relevant* html and css? Currently, when you fix your site, this question won't be useful to future visitors anymore. In addition, it helps if you share your research, tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the bottom margin from the `p` element in the `footer`. For example, update your `layout.css` file to the following (at line 195):

```
footer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```